# Does flyway work with Felix (OSGi) framework?

Tags: flyway

I tried installing the flyway bundle in the felix container. The bundle doesn't start since the MANIFEST.MF file contains a dependency to equinox:

Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.equinox.common

The equinox common library is needed since [flyway](http://code.google.com/p/flyway/source/browse/flyway-core/src/main/java/com/googlecode/flyway/core/util/scanner/osgi/EquinoxCommonResourceUrlResolver.java?spec=svn48aaf2e984b7389a07b4a34234849dd35c4f2094&name=48aaf2e984b7&r=48aaf2e984b7389a07b4a34234849dd35c4f2094) uses the following method to convert "bundle" URLs to ordinary file system URLs:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.FileLocator.toFileURL
```

As far as I can tell this solution will only work in an equinox/eclipse environment but not in a felix environment.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct. Currently only Equinox is supported. Contributions for supporting other OSGi containers are welcome.

Comment: is that still the 'official' point of view? To me it seems that using flyway with the felix framwork is indeed possible...